# Print html tags inside selected tag in python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Suppose this is the dummy html code that I am accessing:

```
<ul class="some class">
          <li id ="a">Arranged in any order</li>
          <li id ="b" >Will still make sense</li>
</ul>
```

I am running a python script to automate a certain website and I need to extract all `li` tags from certain `ul` tag. I have extracted the `ul` tag using the xPath. When I try to print the `ul` using `ul.text`.
It prints:

> Arranged in any order
> Will still make sense

However I want the `li` tags along with the attributes like `id`. Is there any way in selenium to do this thing.
Desired output:

```
 <li id ="a">Arranged in any order</li>
 <li id ="b" >Will still make sense</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# sample html
html = """<ul class="some class">
          <li id ="a">Arranged in any order</li>
          <li id ="b" >Will still make sense</li>
</ul>"""

# create the soup from the html
# when using selenium, replace html with driver.page_source
# soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
# find the ul tag where class is "some class" and then find all the li tags 
lst_of_li = soup.find('ul', class_='some class').findAll('li')
print(lst_of_li)

# [<li id="a">Arranged in any order</li>, <li id="b">Will still make sense</li>]
```

Comment: I can't access the website directly, first I need to login and then I need to scrape this data. In that case how can I run beautifulSoup.

Comment: Just run selenium how you currently are and then do `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')`

Comment: Can you please update the answer with the recent comment, so that, I can mark it as solved and if there is a native way rather than this workaround. I would like to know that as well.

Comment: @Tarster using `BeautifulSoup` is the best way to pull data from `html`